# Regex Validation for Mixed Fractions - Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012, fractions

I'm new to RegEx, working in Visual Studio (C++) and need to check to see if an input is a valid mixed fraction.

So far what I have works for all cases, except I want to make sure that the denominator can't be 0 (eg. 2 3/0 ).

Here's the RegEx I'm currently using:

```
regex mixedFraction("(-?[[:digit:]]+)[\\s]([[:digit:]]+)[/]([[:digit:]]+)")
```

I've tried variations, but can't seem to figure out something that works.  In essence, I really just need it to check that only the first digit of the denominator isn't 0 -- it will be fine for it to fail validation if someone were to enter '2 3/01'

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
regex mixedFraction("(-?[0-9]*)\\s([0-9]*)/([1-9][0-9]*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

i know nothing of c++ or its regex implementation, so syntax might be out slightly:

```
\d+\s\d+/[^0]
```

this will match mixed fractions where denominator is not equal to zero

i dont use those silly `:digit:` thingyamabobs so `\d` will suffice

Comment: I've tried using you recommendation, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried:

[[:digit:]]+/[^0] which didn't seem to change anything, and variations just crashed or didn't compare correctly

Comment: that's no good...it worked for me but like i said i'm more than naive when it comes to c++'s regexes and have no way of testing c++. but you found your answer so all good :)